# How to change xhtml font color in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, colors, editor

[image]

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1, this is a .xhtml page in the editor.

In the above image, how to change the "font-family" , "font-style" color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it : fonts & colors -> CSS -> Property Name